# How do I trigger a button in an html page, from my android app?

Tags: android, html, android-studio, raspberry-pi

I am working on a simple Home Automation project, using Raspberry Pi3. The basic idea is to have an `Android` app which can switch on/off an electric bulb. I have created a simple `HTML` web page which runs a `python` script to turn on/off the connected relay to the light bulb, whenever I press the corresponding buttons on the web page.

**What i want to achieve is to have the buttons on the web page somehow toggled from buttons on a simple `Android` app.**

Please understand that I am almost entirely new to app development and have no interests in further pursuing it. So I am looking for some workaround maybe, or a quick solution that helps me use my already functional web page, just from a simple android app. I would be able to implement the development part, hopefully, if I can get an idea of what exactly do I have to develop for achieving the above mentioned functionality.

Comment: making html buttons to get pressed when Android buttons are pressed is something too wrong. Instead you want to perform the operations, which are performed when the HTML button is clicked (run python code)

Comment: I thought so. But the thing is that I want to web interface (the web page) to be consistent with the app interface. For that I would require the web page button status to get toggled whenever I toggle the app interface buttons. How do I cross that hurdle?

Comment: so you show the web interface as well?

Comment: Like in the app itself? What I am planning is that the entire project be functional on both android smartphones and desktop computers. So on desktops, I want the web interface to be consistent with the app, which I am operating simultaneously on my smartphone.